Netgear switch fan fault
I have just bought a (second hand) Netgear JGS516PE (16 port PoE switch). When I first powered it up, I heard the fan come on. It seemed a little noisy, however I wasn't sure how much of that was to be expected and how much was a worn fan.
I opened the unit, and cleaned it (including the fan) with compressed air. It was quite clean, only a little bit of dirt. Whilst experimenting with the switch / playing with the web interface, it was sitting under my desk and as far as I am aware, the fan ran constantly.
I then installed it in my network, currently running 2 PoE devices and various non-PoE devices. After a while, I noticed the fan was stopped, and the Amber 'Fan' LED was illuminated, indicating a fan fault. Periodically, the fan will run for a few seconds, before shutting down again. I opened the switch again and inspected everything, and lubricated the fan. When I powered it up (Without the case on, initially) the fan ran steadily for several minutes. I then plugged some devices back in to 'load' the switch, and the fan ran OK. Hopeful, I reinstalled into the network, and unfortunately the same issue is back.
It has been running all night like this, and although quite hot is still going strong (With no fan). I power cycled the switch, and upon startup the fan runs for about 2 minutes, before the fault occurs.
Is this indicative of a fault with the actual fan, or the switch itself (Fan control, etc)? Has anyone else experienced anything similar?
I can get a new fan, however the shipping will be ~2 weeks, will it harm the switch running hot until then?
Any input appreciated.
-- UPDATE 26/08/24 --
Have been running the switch with a small USB-powered desk fan blowing on one corner of the case in an effort to keep it cool and I have not been paying much attention to whether the fan has been running or not. The fan fault light has been on most of the time.
The replacement fan just arrived, and before installing it, I power cycled the switch again to see what would happen. Surprisingly, the fan fault LED is no longer on and the fan is running, keeping the switch reasonably cool. It has been going like this for ~2 days now. Unsure whether to replace the fan anyway or keep as a spare, I will monitor the switch over the coming days and see what happens...
